# Why I cant get my variable from a required file?

Tags: php

I am doing a pagination system and when I do the 'for' the file does not fetch any variable on require_once 'carregarOpinioes.php'.

In line 33 (

carregarOpinioes.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../../database/config.php');

include '../geral.php';
apenasAdmin();

function connectToDatabase()
{
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        $code = $conn->connect_errno;
        $message = $conn->connect_error;
        printf("<p>Connection error: %d %s</p>", $code, $message);
        return false;
    }
    return $conn;
}


//Conexão à BD
if (!($conn = connectToDatabase())) {
    exit();
}
// Se a página já tiver definida ela vai buscar o valor do $_GET['pagina'] se não tiver ela fica com o valor 1, o ? serve para verificar se o boolean é true ou false.
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

//Selecionar todas as opiniões onde o comentário não está vazio
$sqlOpinioesGeral = "SELECT * FROM opiniao WHERE comentario = ''";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOpinioesGeral);

//Variavel para saber a quantidade total de opiniões existentes na tabela
$totalOpinioes = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Quantidade de opiniões por página
$opPorPagina = 5;

//Calcular o número de páginas totais
$numPaginas = ceil($totalOpinioes/$opPorPagina);

//Calcular o numero da linha da tabela que dá inicio a cada página
$inicio = ($opPorPagina * $pagina) - $opPorPagina;


$query = "SELECT
    u.Nome,
    o.id_opiniao,
    o.qtd_estrelas,
    o.comentario,
    o.data,
    o.aprovacao
FROM
    opiniao o
JOIN utilizador u ON
    (o.id_user = u.id_user)
WHERE
    o.comentario != ''
LIMIT $inicio, $opPorPagina";

$resultDois = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$totalOpinioes = mysqli_num_rows($resultDois);
```

opinioesAdmin.php

```
.
.
.
    <?php
    require_once 'carregarOpinioes.php';
    ?>

    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 page">

                <table class="table table-dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Data</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Avaliação 1-5</th>
                            <th>Comentário</th>
                            <th>Gerir</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while ($dadosOpiniao = mysqli_fetch_object($resultDois)) {
                            echo "
                        <tr>
                            <th scope=\"row\">#" . $dadosOpiniao->id_opiniao . "</th>
                            <td>" . $dadosOpiniao->data . "</td>
                            <td>" . utf8_encode($dadosOpiniao->Nome) . "</td>
                            <td>" . $dadosOpiniao->qtd_estrelas . "</td>
                            <td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn botao botaoComentario\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal" . $dadosOpiniao->id_opiniao . "\"><i class=\"far fa-eye\"></i></button>
                                <div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"modal" . $dadosOpiniao->id_opiniao . "\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"exampleModalLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\">
                                    <div class=\"modal-dialog\" role=\"document\">
                                        <div class=\"modal-content\">
                                            <div class=\"modal-header\">
                                                <h5 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"exampleModalLabel\">Opinião de " . utf8_encode($dadosOpiniao->Nome) . "</h5>
                                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Fechar\">
                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"modal-body\">
                                                <p>«" . utf8_encode(utf8_decode($dadosOpiniao->comentario)) . "»</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Fechar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class=\"formsJuntos\">
                                    <form><button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn botao botaoAprovar\"><i class=\"fas fa-check\"></i></button></form>
                                    <form><button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn botao botaoApagar\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></button></form>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr> ";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        for ($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) {
                            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="opinioesAdmin.php?pagina=<?' . $i . '">'. $i .'</a></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

Currently the output is   1  
But it should be   2   
because $resultDois has 8 rows!
I am hoping this community can help me.

Comment: You have a lot going on here. Limit your code to just the `require` and the required file. See if you can get that to work. If so, build from there. If not, post those reduced code blocks.

Comment: I already answered the solution, it was a SQL mistake is it possible to delete this publication?

Comment: You can clean it up, if you think there's value for others. If it's just a mistake and you want it removed, flag it.

Comment: how i flag my question?

Comment: I think it requires certain privilege. I flagged it.

Comment: thanks, sry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sry, my bad. That's a operator mistake on $sqlOpinioesGeral = "SELECT * FROM opiniao WHERE comentario **= ''**"; I wanted !=